# Type identification: Rödelheim Hebrew typeface

Tags: font-identification

I've been looking for a modern typeface similar to that used in the old Rödelheim siddurim and machzorim (prayerbooks) printed by Heidenheim, Lehrberger, and Kaufmann over the course of the 19th and early 20th centuries. However, as there seems to be a relative lack of suitable search tools for Hebrew type, I've come up empty.

An typeface answer would include all letters, typographer's variants, vowel points and cantillation, and ideally be configured to take advantage of OpenType features.

Below is a sample from a 19th century Rödelheim siddur.

[image: Sample Rödelheim siddur page]

Comment: Have you attempted to look through this? https://opensiddur.org/help/fonts/

Comment: Looks like Taamey Ashkenaz is a good match.

Comment: @simon, I think you're right. I figured this out a couple of days before your comment, actually

Answer (score 1):

Per [Simon](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/132310/simon)'s comment above, [Ta'amey Ashkenaz](https://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/fonts/display-font-charmap.php?fnt=TaameyAshkenaz) is very similar, if not identical, to the typeface used in Rödelheim Hebrew type.